# Sandbox does not allow access to com.apple.dnssd.service, Cocoa macOS and Firebase Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, sandbox

I'm new in swift development. I'm creating a storyboard app for ios and macOS connected with firebase firestore Storage.

In ios everthing works fine with read/write data in Firebase.

But on the macOS side I'm struggling with configuring firebase.

[This hapend when i try to read data from firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kYHZ.png)

The Sandbox checkbox for macOS Target are checked.

**Incoming network connections (server)
and
Outgoing network connections (client)**

Answer (score 0):

On macOS you need to enable `network` capabilities for your app to have access to the internet.

To fix that, go into Target Settings -> Signing & Capabilities and check:

- Incoming network connections (server).
- Outgoing network connections (client)